# Bernoulli differential equation alike

Tags: differential

I am quite new to differential equations and I have the following
$$
\partial u(x)/\partial x = a(x)u(x)^2+b(x)u(x)+c(x)
$$
which is, to the best of my knowledge, not exactly a Bernoulli differential equation because of $c(x)$. Does anyone know which kind of equation is the one above and how to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Riccati differential equation.  There is no known way to solve it in general, but there are some strategies that work in many cases.  You might look at this [Maple help page](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=odeadvisor/Riccati).

Comment: Thanks! For my purposes it will suffice to be able to solve it numerically